# the counterexample of the pinsker inequality.

Tags: measure-theory, information-theory

if P and Q are probability measures over a set X, and P is absolutely continuous with respect to Q,then set
$$ D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P\|Q) = \int_X \ln\frac{{\rm d}P}{{\rm d}Q} \, {\rm d}P, $$

set
$$D_{\mathrm{TV}}(P\|Q) =2\sup\{|P(E)-Q(E)|\big| E\in \mathcal{F}\}$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra of $X$

the Pinsker theorem said:
$$D_{TV}\le\sqrt{\frac{D_{KL}}{2}}$$

but the reverse is not true:

for $\forall\varepsilon>0$,there exist $P,Q$ such that
$$D_{TV}<\varepsilon,D_{KL}=\infty$$

Could you show me such an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $P,Q$ such that $D_{TV} < \epsilon$ but the support of $P$ - support of $Q$ has positive measure under $P$. Then $D(P||Q) = \infty$.

You can do this with the counting measure and $P$ being $0$ with probabilty $1-\epsilon$ and $1$ with probability $\epsilon$, $Q$ being $0$ with probability $1-\epsilon$ and $2$ with probability $\epsilon$. The total variation distance is $\epsilon$, but the KL divergence is infinite.

Comment: Sorry,I don't quite understand your example.Do you mean counting meausre on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $P(\{0\})=1-\varepsilon$ and $P(\{1\})=1-\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: On $\mathbb{N}$. Fix $0< \epsilon \leq 1$. If $X \sim P$, $P(X=0) = 1- \epsilon, P(X=1) = \epsilon$. If $X \sim Q$, $P(X=0) = 1-\epsilon$ and $P(X=2) = \epsilon$. Direct calculation shows the total variation distance is $\epsilon$. However, the KL divergence ($\sum_i p(i) \log \frac{p(i)}{q(i)}$ where $p,q$ are the probability mass functions corresponding to $P,Q$ respectively) is infinite since you have $\epsilon \log \frac{\epsilon}{0}$ in that sum.

Comment: You are right,$D_{KL}(P\|Q)=\infty$